# Can I prevent invoking destructor before overloaded delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'd like to use boost.pool. It's okay if you don't know about it. Basically, it has two main functions, malloc() and free().

I've overloaded new and delete for my custom defined class test.

```
class test
{
public:

    test()
    {
        cout    << "ctor" << endl;
    }

    ~test()
    {
        cout    << "dtor" << endl;
    }

    void*   operator new(size_t) throw()
    {
        cout    << "custom operator new" << endl;
        return _pool.malloc();
    }

    void    operator delete(void* p)
    {
        cout    << "custom operator delete" << endl;
        _pool.free(p);
    }

    void    show()
    {
        cout    << _i << endl;
    }

private:
    int _i;
    static boost::pool<>    _pool;
};// class test

boost::pool<>   test::_pool(sizeof(test));
```

When I create instance of test using new, constructor was not called but if I delete it, destructor **was** called. Why? and can I avoid it?

Comment: Seems you changed half of the occurences of 'yoon' to 'test'

Comment: Your destructor name does not match up with the class name.  Please show your actual code.

Comment: When yoon replaced with test and added a main like test* p = new test; delete p;, the output is "custom new/ctor/dtor/custom delete". It needs a complete and compilable example.

Comment: sorry, I've modified the code. yoon -> test

Comment: my main is test* p = new test; delete p and the output is 'custom operator new/dtor/custom operator delete' with my g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce, when added

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/pool/pool.hpp>
using namespace std;
```

(why do people omit such things that are necessary to make the code compile?!) and

```
int main()
{
    test* p = new test;
    delete p;
}
```

This is either a stripped-down and modified version that doesn't have that behavior or your compiler may be broken (which version is it?)

In any case your aim should be *getting the constructor called*, rather than getting destructor not called. Overloaded operator new just deals with raw memory allocation, the built-in new-expression should use that to obtain the memory and then call the constructor to create an instance there.

Edit: the only way I can reproduce your output is by circumventing the built-in new-expression:

```
test* p = static_cast<test*>(test::operator new(sizeof (test)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because the global operator new is getting called? Anyways, just a comment about your class...

operator new and operator delete are always *static* (even if you don't write the keyword), so it's good practice to use *static* in the declaration.

You declared operator new with throw(), meaning that it won't throw. But you use a statement (iostreaming) that can throws. Maybe you should surround that with try/catch and create an [std::nothrow_t](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=170) version.